# jquery update class of the same name throughout page

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I am trying to do a foreach on class ajax-link so i can load text from an ajax call but the code is only upsating on the first ajax-link on the page. All the others in the page are not being updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
        $(".ajax-link").each(function(){            
          var href = $(this).attr('href') + '?request=ajax&boo=' + $(this).text(); //URL
          alert(href); // Is It working?
        $(this).load(href); //Create the xmlHttpRequest
     return false; //Stop the HTTP request  
        });                 
    });
```

Comment: @AlienWebguy Won't removing the return false cause the HTTP request to not stop, dont i need to stop the request when its done?

Comment: No, the server will tell the browser when to close the connection. What you can do is expand that load function a bit to include success and error handling: `load(href function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == 'error') {
    var msg = 'Error: ';
    $('#error').html(msg + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
  }
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return false;` will break you out of the `each()` statement. You need to remove that.